# Subclassing an Edit control with SHAutoComplete applied

Tags: winapi, subclassing

I'm new, so sorry if the question isn't posed exactly as you're get used to.

I inevitably need to subclass an Edit control for which `SHAutoComplete()` has been called like this:

```
// initialization
if FAILED( CoInitialize(NULL) ) exit(1);
// creation of an Edit control
HWND hEdit=CreateWindow( WC_EDIT, ... );
// calling SHAutoComplete - I essentially understand this as a subclassing behind the scenes
SHAutoComplete( hEdit , SHACF_AUTOSUGGEST_FORCE_ON|SHACF_FILESYSTEM );
// subclassing an Edit box for which SHAutoComplete has been called
WNDPROC autoCompleteWndProc=SubclassWindow( hEdit , __myNewWndProc__ ); // using macro
```

Suppose the `__myNewWndProc__` function looks like a classic window procedure:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK __myNewWndProc__(HWND hEdit, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    // handle subclass-specific messages
    switch (msg){ ... }
    // handle SHAutoComplete-specific messages
    return autoCompleteWndProc(hEdit,msg,wParam,lParam); // <-- here's the problem (read further)
}
```

The problem is, it doesn't work.  The application crashes with error:

> Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)" (access violation)

pointing the problem at line marked in the above listing.

The question is what am I doing wrong?

(I've experienced the same problem when subclassing from ComboBoxEx, but I managed to work around it, but can't find any trick with the `SHAutoComplete()` problem.)

Comment: Use `SetWindowSubclass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SubclassWindow()` is a wrapper for [`SetWindowLongPtr()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx):

```
#define     SubclassWindow(hwnd, lpfn)       \
              ((WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr((hwnd), GWLP_WNDPROC, (LPARAM)(WNDPROC)(lpfn)))
```

When you use that type of subclassing, you **MUST** use [`CallWindowProc()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633571.aspx) to call the previous window procedure when needed, **DO NOT** call the procedure directly:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK __myNewWndProc__(HWND hEdit, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    //...
    // handle SHAutoComplete-specific messages
    return CallWindowProc(autoCompleteWndProc,hEdit,msg,wParam,lParam);
}
```

The reason for that is stated in the documentation:

[SetWindowLongPtr function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx)

> Calling SetWindowLongPtr with the GWLP_WNDPROC index creates a subclass of the window class used to create the window. An application can subclass a system class, but should not subclass a window class created by another process. The SetWindowLongPtr function creates the window subclass by changing the window procedure associated with a particular window class, causing the system to call the new window procedure instead of the previous one. **An application must pass any messages not processed by the new window procedure to the previous window procedure by calling CallWindowProc. This allows the application to create a chain of window procedures.**

[CallWindowProc function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633571.aspx):

> lpPrevWndFunc [in]
>   Type: WNDPROC
>
> The previous window procedure. If this value is obtained by calling the GetWindowLong function with the nIndex parameter set to GWL_WNDPROC or DWL_DLGPROC, it is actually either the address of a window or dialog box procedure, **or a special internal value meaningful only to CallWindowProc.**

You are probably running into the latter case, which will crash trying to call something that is not directly callable.

With that said, you should not be using `SetWindowLongPtr()` to subclass.  Use [`SetWindowSubClass()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102.aspx) instead.  Read the following articles for more details:

[Subclassing Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Safer subclassing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/11/55653.aspx)